# Shortcut for "disable object in the viewport" (DOV) Blender 2.8

Tags: shortcut

I'd like to use the Collections like layers early versions of Blender. It is working well. But.
I use procedural boolean objects and need to hide the boolean parts. I created a part in a collection. But when I switch to another collection and back then all hidden elements are visible again.
I use the disable object in the viewport (DOV) and it's great.
BUT
There is a shortcut for hide (H, ALT H) and I can work fast, but I can't figure out: HOW I SWITCH DOV WITH SHORTCUT for fast developing.

Need a shortcut for DOV.
Please help...
Gabor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know your question was asked many months ago, but in case you never found an answer, you can assign a shortcut for 'Disable In Viewports' by rightclicking the 'Disable In Viewports' icon in the outliner and clicking the 'Assign Shortcut' submenu

1 enable DIV icon in outliner

[image: screenshot enable DIV icon in outliner]

2 rightclick DIV to assign shortcut

[image: screenshot rightclick DIV to assign shortcut]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Have you tried holding shift and using num buttons (shift+1, shift+2 etc.) this way you can add and hide visibility of collections? Hope it helps!