# Weight Paint Mode: Hidden faces keep unhiding

Tags: weight-painting

I'm new to weight painting in Blender.

One thing continues to drive me nuts, when I try to hide disconnected parts of the mesh in *Weight Paint* mode, they keep re-appearing the moment I start painting.

Is this expected behavior and I'm doing something wrong? Is it a bug?

[image]

Comment: Maybe as an alternative, instead of hiding the object, you can disable it in viewport and then turn it back on when you need it. See if that still causes the bug. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126941/shortcut-for-disable-object-in-the-viewport-dov-blender-2-8 I also suggest reporting this bug! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTD0OJq_rF4

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that fixes the problem. If you separate the mesh that is having the issue into it's own separate object and join it back to the original mesh then the problem seems to disappear all together.